# Checking to see if a class is present on a checkbox

Tags: jquery

This is not working

```
$(".gradeA, .gradeU").find(":checkbox").click(function() {
if (this.checked === false) { return; }
if (this.hasClass("toggler")) { return; }
```

The last line is failing but i need to check to see if its this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCB" value="A" class="toggler" />Couldn't find the Venue<br />
```

Comment: i dont understand, if you need to "check to see if its a checkbox", then how will the "this.checked" line above work if its not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hasClass()` is a member method of the `jQuery` object. so you need to enclose the `this` in the `$()` function, otherwise you are trying to call the `hasClass()` method on the DOM object, which doesn't have `hasClass()` as a member function.

Passing `this` as a parameter to the `jQuery` object (often shortened to `$`) will return a `jQuery` object which does have `hasClass()` as a member method, and then everyone is happy and pixies can dance around the campfire again.

```
if (this.hasClass("toggler")) { return; }    //Your Code, wrong.
if ($(this).hasClass("toggler")) { return; } //My Code, right.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index) {
  if($(this).attr('class')=='toggler')
    alert ('yes class is there');
  else
    alert ('no class is not there');
});
```

or

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("toggler")) { alert("yes class is there"); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also check it using [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$(this).is('.toggler');
```